# Download specific VHD file using Azcopy

Tags: azure, vhd, azcopy

my Azure storage container having multiple VHD files so how can i download specific VHD file to local using AZ-copy tool.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
AzCopy /Source:"https://[accountname].blob.core.windows.net/[containername]/" /Dest:"[folder path e.g. d:\test\]" /SourceKey:[account key] /Pattern:"[vhd file name]"
```

Replace `[accountname]`, `[containername]`, `[folder path]`, `[account key]` and `[vhd file name]` with appropriate values.